# Is it illegal to stop a car for a pedestrian crossing in China?

Tags: road-vehicles, law, china

Today while preparing for one of my classes, this time on law, I found the snippet on a great many websites saying that in China:

> Drivers of power-driven vehicles are forbidden to stop at pedestrian crossings or they risk a 5RMB fine.

- [Example](http://hntbat.com/laws/drivers-of-power-driven-vehicles-are-forbidden-to-stop-at-pedestrian-crossings-or-they-risk-a-5rmb-fine/).

Now, I have a Chinese driver's license and I remember in the test that you must stop at a pedestrian crossing if there are pedestrians using it. However, the common practice in China is to not stop for anything - just blow the horn and swerve through the gaps.

So my question is, was there ever any basis to the above law quote forbidding you to stop? Did such a law exist before or is it all just a fabrication or urban myth?

Comment: Chinese don't strike me as a people that would paint pedestrian crossings that serve no purpose (well, one could say they'd serve as designated kill zones, but that still seems a bit silly).

Comment: Looks like bad translation. Rules in most of the world prohibit stopping **on** the crossing, car must yield to the pedestrians stopping **before** the crossing.

Answer (score 11):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_Traffic_Safety_Law_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China), recent (2004) Chinese road laws now dictate:

> Under the new law, when accidents occur between pedestrians or non-motorised vehicles and motor vehicles, except for the case where the pedestrian or the non-motorised vehicle deliberately causes the incident, the motorist must always bear responsibility. Responsibility for the motorist is reduced if the pedestrian or non-motorised side violated traffic laws.

It references the [new law](http://www.gov.cn/banshi/2005-08/23/content_25575_2.htm) (written in Chinese). Using the translation given in [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1623/43), we get:

> Article 47: When a motor vehicle vehicle passes through a crosswalk, it should proceed at reduced speed; in the case when a pedestrian is crossing the crosswalk, the vehicle should stop and yield to the pedestrian.

As one might expect, it seems clear that the original claim is false.

Comment: I have asked for it on our [Chinese SE](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1623/43). :)

Comment: Not really answering the question. I am aware of the existing regulations having sat the Chinese driving test myself. The question is, was there ever, in the past, a rule such as quoted above?